# ERROR: JETTY_HOME not set

Tags: ubuntu, jetty

I have tried installing Jetty server on my Ubuntu 12.04 following this steps. But when I start my server I get the following error,

service jetty start
** ERROR: JETTY_HOME not set, you need to set it or install in a standard location

Comment: Have you considered doing exactly that?

Comment: Yes I tried doing the same by adding in /etc/environment but ended up with the same error. As far as I searched JETTY doesn't need the variable to be set explicitly and is set by Jetty's start mechanism. (start.jar)

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/q/374699/127106

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pointer in the right direction: JETTY_HOME refers to an environment variable set with a value corresponding to the directory path where you have installed jetty.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655641/set-environment-variable-in-ubuntu

Comment: I am new to linux after years of using window and hence having some difficulties. I followed this tutorial to install Jetty  [link](http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jetty-9/#comment-9071) step by step and was getting the mentioned error. I did google and I did try setting the environment variable explicitly but wasnt working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather frustrating error with little help out there. I thought I'd post my solution here for someone who is looking to solve the same problem.

Anyway, the correct solution is to set `JETTY_HOME` in `/etc/default/jetty` like so:

```
 JETTY_HOME=/opt/jetty
```

Hope this helps someone.